# Some of the columns of a table are not displayed in popup display ABAP

Tags: popup, abap

I'm assigning a button to display my table at SAP. I've achieved this with popup_with_table_display. In the popup screen I can see some of my columns but not all of them. Here's my code:

```
DATA: t_interview TYPE TABLE OF ZBS_HR_I0001

CASE sy-ucomm.
  WHEN 'DISP'.
select * from ZBS_HR_I0001 into table t_interview.
CALL FUNCTION 'POPUP_WITH_TABLE_DISPLAY'
  EXPORTING
    ENDPOS_COL         = 100
    ENDPOS_ROW         = 10
    STARTPOS_COL       = 10
    STARTPOS_ROW       = 1
    TITLETEXT          = 'Interview Table'
  TABLES
    VALUETAB           = t_interview
  EXCEPTIONS
    BREAK_OFF          = 1
    OTHERS             = 2
          .
```

BTW this code section works inside my PAI.
[Here's the output that I'm getting.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ScAlg.png) 
[And here's the original table with all of its columns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2kTAq.png). How can I make it display all of my columns?

Comment: Inside the function module the output of one line is hardcoded to 80 characters as maximum. With this function module it is not possible to display a line completely, which is longer than 80 characters.

Comment: The class `cl_salv_table` might help you.

Comment: @Philipp I've tried it yesterday and didn't seem to work that's why I was trying this function. Now I've tried this class and now it works.

Comment: @JózsefSzikszai thanks for the info I had no idea.

Comment: @hekean1339 `and now it works` if it works, please post full solution so it will help others

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the working code for me:

```
DATA: t_interview TYPE TABLE OF ZBS_HR_I0001,
      ts_interview TYPE REF TO cl_salv_table.

select * from ZBS_HR_I0001 into table t_interview.
cl_salv_table=>factory(
  IMPORTING
    r_salv_table = ts_interview
  CHANGING
    t_table      = t_interview
).

CASE sy-ucomm.
  WHEN 'DISP'.
   ts_interview->display( ).
ENDCASE.
```